# Lineset sizing for multi-zone mini-split

Tags: copper-tubing, mini-split

I'm installing a 48k multi-zone mini-split in the garage.  The zones are 18k, 18k and 12k.  All of the indoor units say they require 1/4" x 1/2" linesets in the install manuals.  The condenser has 5 x 1/4" liquid ports, 3 x 3/8" and 2 x 1/2" gas ports.  I checked with the vendor, and they said adapters are provided with the condenser, so ok to use 3/8" linesets on gas side for the indoor units.
My question:  Is it really ok to use 3/8" linesets and adapters on the gas side in this setup?

Comment: Given that the manufacturer gives you the opportunity to use 1/2" linesets on the larger ports, why not use them?

Comment: Vendor sent 1/4 x 3/8, but I will probably exchange them.

Answer (score 0):

I would do what the oem tells you but 3/8 on a 18k sounds a bit small to me but  the oem should know.

I am sure the last 18k I installed required 1/2” on the low and 1/4 on the high.
I would rather use the larger ports for your larger (18k) inside units as throttled suction line will reduce their efficiency.

yes you only have 42 max But if the return line is throttled on the larger ones they may suffer more because of the under sized suction line.
I may be out of line here as I don’t know the brand or control system but if in parallel with the flow controlled in the head unit go with a larger suction line on the 18k units and skip using the adapters

They would not make the suction line on the inside units 1/2” if it did not need it in my opinion. But I only do hvac part time.